# R - How to create array from console input

Tags: r, input, console, command, output

Hi all and thanks in advance for all your help.

In R, I'm sending a command to an external Windows program using `system(command)`, which in turn outputs lines (with multiple values per line) that I see directly on the R console. They look something like this:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h    
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8    
3,4,5,7,1,3,4,9    
7,5,3,1,8,1,5,7
```

What I would like to do is create an array that has the top row as column names and each subsequent row from the input should be the values that go into these columns. Any and all help in making this work would be very appreciated.

This is my first foray into this territory so I'm quite stuck as to how to do it. I've meddled with `scan()`, `pipe()` and `readLines()` but haven't been able to succeed. I have no particular attachment to `system(command)`, any function that will run the executable that will give me the output I need is fine by me if it helps achieve what I want.

Comment: Did you try setting the `intern` argument of `system`?  Supposedly returns the output as a character vector.  Then you could do something like `read.table(text = system(command, intern=TRUE), sep = ",", header=TRUE`)

Comment: What system are you working with?

Comment: Thanks user1935457, that actually did the trick. It is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment made by user1935457 did the trick.

`read.table(text = system(command, intern=TRUE), sep = ",", header=TRUE)`